# Debian & macOS UTF-8 compatibility

Tags: debian, utf-8

I've installed a new server machine with Debian 12 (console only), which was configured during installation with the locale `en_US.UTF-8`.

With the screen and keyboard connected to the machine, I can type and create folders with accented characters with no issues.

I've copied some folders to this machine from a macOS system using `scp`. All folders with accented characters show gibberish when viewed on the physical Debian console screen. A folder called `élément` on macOS displays as `*l*ment` (* being some symbol).

When logged in to the Debian machine via SSH from the same remote macOS machine, folder names appear with escaped characters (e.g. `'$'\303\251''l'$'\303\251''mentaire`). I've looked for some answers and found that the name displays correctly after unchecking, in the macOS Terminal, Profiles > Advanced > "Set locale environment variables on startup".

I configured a SMB share on the Debian machine and mounted it on the macOS machine. Folder names appear as they should.

The only issue is the fact that, if I'm using a screen physically connected to the Debian machine, I can't view or access any of those folders (although, as mentioned above, I can create *new* folders with special characters without problems, although they render with accented characters on the macOS Terminal).

It doesn't seem to be a big deal at the moment since the machine will mostly be used via SSH, but I'd like to understand what's causing it, what can be done about it and whether it might cause issues later on. A Linux application installed on the Debian machine and serving files via a web server finds and displays the filenames correctly.

Entering `locale` on the Debian machine outputs many values, all set to `en_US.UTF-8` with the exception of `LC_ALL=` which isn't set to anything. I've tried `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` but this didn't help.

On the macOS machine, entering `locale` outputs:

```
LANG=""
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

Any ideas?

Comment: yup, use Google for how to set lc_all debian bookwork default - since you did no research infront of the posting imho

Comment: I've spent an entire day on the issue before posting and I believe I've read all the articles in my first 30 Google searches — that's the reason I tried to set `LC_ALL` in the first place — but you are free to assume the contrary, of course.